# Mongoose pushing to an Array using presave middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-middleware

I'm trying to update an array using presave hooks available in mongoose. Im using this array for Audit Purposes and hence i wanted to enforce correct values using these middle wares

Here is my schema

```
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
id: { type: String, required: true },
status: { type: String, required: true },
code: { type: String, required: true }, // ENQUIRY
events:{
    type:[{
            status: {type: String, required: true},
            date:{ type: Date, required: true}

    }], required: false
},
assignedTo: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: false },
}, {timestamps:true});
```

The logic works great in save middleware hook.

```
taskSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    try {
        let event = {}
        let now = Date.now();
        event.status = this.status;
        event.date = now;
        this.events.push(event);
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        next(error);
    }
});
```

Error when used in findOneAndUpdate hook

```
taskSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function(next) {
    try {

        let event={}
        let now = Date.now();
        event.status = this._update.status;
        event.date = now;
        this.events.push(event);
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        next(error);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  Here is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I see that this.events is undefined.

How do I access that array to have it updated?  I also should ignore whatever is sent in request.body.events

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [Types of Middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware), `save` is **document middleware** and `findOneAndUpdate` is **query middleware**. And in [notes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes), it says that:

> Query middleware differs from document middleware in a subtle but important way: in document middleware, `this` refers to the document being updated. In query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have a reference to the document being updated, so `this` refers to the query object rather than the document being updated.

So in your `findOneAndUpdate` pre, `this.events` is `undefined`.

In your case, using below code may solve the problem:

```
taskSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function(next) {
  try {

    let event={}
    let now = Date.now();
    event.status = this._update.status;
    event.date = now;
    this._update['$push'] = {events: event};
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I did understand the difference between document and Query middlewares. The difficulty here is the events array will not be a part of the query object . 

Events array needs to be fetched from the document in the db . 

So the workaround here is to fetch and update the events array before calling the findOneAndUpdate function .